# Opening chrome in incognito with a url

Tags: vb.net

I'm expanding on a little programming work I'm doing, and I'm using process.start() to open chrome in incognito mode, but I also want it to open a url in the incognito mode. This is my code:

```
    Dim chrome As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    Dim param As String = "/incognito"
    Dim sURL As String = txtCustomURL.Text
    Process.Start(chrome, param)
    Process.Start(sURL)

End Sub
```

This didn't work, it opens a incognito tab but opens the url in a normal window. Is there a way I can open a url in incognito mode like this (baring in mind I'm a beginner at VB)?

Comment: You are calling `Process.Start` twice. Try `Process.Start(chrome, param + " " + sURL)`.

Comment: Thank you! can i ask, what does the + " " + do in the process.start()?

Comment: It's just string concatenation - adding a space between the two parameters. I added an answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling Process.Start twice:

- The first one runs Chrome.exe with the parameter `/incognito`;
- the second runs your URL, which Windows will launch with the default browser.

You need to launch Chrome.exe with *two* parameters: `/incognito`, and the url to open.

Chrome (and most other programs) accept parameters separated by spaces. So the format of your parameters should end up like `/incognito http://www.google.com`

Therefore, try passing chrome a string consisting of `param`, a space, and then the URL, concatenated together with `&`:

```
Process.Start(chrome, param & " " & sURL)
```

Comment: Not mine, but I'd bet it is nitpicking that you used `+` rather than `&` for string concat

Comment: Ah, I always forget that when switching from C# to VB.

Answer (score 0):

This works from VBScript, passing -incognito as a parameter:

```
siteA = "https://google.com"
Set browobj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
browobj.Run "chrome -incognito -url "&siteA
Set browobj = Nothing
```

Comment: That's excellent thank you. Works perfectly